# Bulk Regex Pattern Match

Tags: java, regex

I have a bulk no of regex pattern in my database. Each regex pattern having his own id.

```
    For example:
    ID    Pattern
    123   ^((?=.*\bjava\b)(?=.*\bpostgres\b).*)$
    456   ^((?=.*\b.net\b)(?=.*\bsql\s*server\b).*)$
```

I have a content which contains different kinds of skills information.
I want to match all these regex patterns with the above content.
Is it possible to match all regex in single shot and retrieve the ID field itself.

Comment: Not sure what your after, perhaps you can post what you've already tried and illustrate what you want to achieve with an example.

Comment: You want a regex to match all of these regexes or a way to create a matcher with all of these regexes on a string?

Comment: Yes i need a matcher with all of these regexes on a string.

Comment: If by "one shot" you mean a one-liner (with the appropriate backing methods), that is of course possible. If you, on the other hand, mean a single pass through your string, with O(n) complexity, that is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work. Regex can used on the content but only gives you information about the match position. Your ID doesn't have anything to do with the expression itself, so I don't see a way to relate the ID to the expression other then to iterate over all expressions and check which one finds a positive match in the content and then returning the ID of the expression.

Comment: Finally you people saying no other way to do like this. Thanks for your comments.